# Grant postgres superuser to linux account

Tags: postgresql, linux

On my development (Ubuntu linux) laptop I have a **postgres** OS account, which owns the Postgres installation.

When I want to perform any postgres activities, create/drop databases etc, I must first su to the postgres account.

```
$ sudo su postgres
```

How can I alter my own OS account to have the OS-level privilages of **postgres**, so I will not need to **su** ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Create the user on the OS**

```
# Identify yourself as root
su - 

# Create the user who will have access to a postgres database
useradd mypostgresuser

# Add a password
passwd mypostgresuser
```

**Give local users access to postgres**

You need to locate the data directory for your postgresql install, i.e. where you have created the database files. They are typically located in `/var/lib/pgsql/data`.
The value for your install might be available in the environment variable `$PGDATA`

```
# Make sure that local users can access postgres
cat /${PGDATA}/pg_hba.conf

# this was the default setting on my 8.4 install
# TYPE  DATABASE    USER        CIDR-ADDRESS          METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all         all
```

if you make any changes, reloading postgres will be necessary

```
/etc/init.d/postgresql reload
```

Or as postgres

```
pg_ctl reload -D ${PGDATA}
```

**Now connect to psql as postgres**

```
# Create the user in postgres
postgres=# create user mypostgresuser;
CREATE ROLE

# Give that user access to a database
postgres=# grant all privileges on database mytestdb to mypostgresuser;
GRANT
```

**Test the connection**

```
# Identify yourself as mypostgresuser
su - mypostgresuser

# Connect to the database
psql -d mytestdb
```

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. I followed the steps, but is it correct I will need to re-grant access every time a database is created? This is done frequently. I could add it to the import/ grant scripts if necessary.

Comment: You must GRANT rights to every new database for normal users. Only the postgres user has access to all objects by default.

Comment: I see. Ok thanks Craig. I guess I'll have to keep sudo'ing as I am constantly creating and importing datbases from a remote server. Cheers.

Comment: Just for info, if you need to give a user access to an existing database, you can grant your new user the role that already has access. GRANT ROLE nameofexistingrole TO newrole;

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [`pg_ident.conf`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/auth-username-maps.html) to map a system user to a postgresql user.

**1. Edit pg_ident.conf**

For example, to allow the "root" user to run `psql` as the "postgres" user (`psql -U postgres ...`), map it in `pg_ident.conf` by adding a line like

```
root2pg  root  postgres
```

**2. Edit pg_hba.conf**

Then in `pg_hba.conf`, change this line:

```
local  all  postgres  peer
```

to add "map=root2pg" at the end:

```
local  all  postgres  peer map=root2pg
```

**3. Restart postgresql**

```
systemctl restart postgresql
```

You can use any string you like for the map name (here "root2pg"), and allow other users than root (the 2nd column in pg_ident.conf)

To make this very generic and easy to copy paste to different machines which may have several different postgresql versions, you could do it with something like:

```sh
allow=root; as=postgres;

export mapname=${allow}2$as 
printf '%-16s%-24s%s\n' $mapname $allow $as >> /etc/postgresql/*/main/pg_ident.conf
perl -i.bak -pe 's/(^local\s+all\s+postgres\s+peer)\s*$/$1 map=$ENV{mapname}\n/' /etc/postgresql/*/main/pg_hba.conf
```

(The use of printf instead of echo is only to align with the existing columns in the default pg_ident.conf)